# dijit declarative event handlers

Tags: html, css, dojo

I'm trying to declare a `dijit TextBox` but I'm not able to attach the `focus` event to it.

I've tried doing so declaratively:

```
<div class="midArea_div">
 <div class="searchBox_div">
   <input type="text" data-dojo-name="searchBox_input" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" data-dojo-props="placeHolder:'Search...'"class="searchBox"></input>
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="onFocus" data-dojo-args="evt">
         alert("hi");
   </script>
 <div class="searchIcon_overlay"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

and also programatically. http://jsfiddle.net/YyFw5/

### js:

```
require([
  "dijit/dijit",
  "dojo/parser",
  "maqetta/space",
  "maqetta/AppStates",
  "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
  "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
  "dijit/form/TextBox",
  "dojo/on"
]);
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/fx", "dojo/on", "dijit/registry"], function(ready, dom, base_fx, on, registry){
     ready(function(){
         // logic that requires that Dojo is fully initialized should go here
        //on(registry.byId("searchBox_input"), "focus", function(a){alert("hi");});
     });
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle won't run because jsfiddle uses the google-hosted dojo library, which causes a 404 on the maqetta libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **declarative** example you are using the `dojo/on` module, which performs its own normalization of native DOM events. The `onFocus` callback is a Dijit widget construct (mixed into _WidgetBase via the _FormMixin if you want to look at source) that is used when a widget becomes "active" because it, or widget inside of it has focus or has been clicked.

You want to use the [normalized event name](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/quickstart/events.html#events-available-for-connection) with your event handler as follows:

```
<script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="focus" data-dojo-args="evt">
     alert("hi");
</script>
```

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your **programmatic** example, except that you are calling `registry.byId("searchBox_input")` with an ID that (from your code example) does not exist. Perhaps you should add an `id` key to your `data-dojo-props` or as an attribute on your `<input>` node.